# How to export the output of sp_AskBrent?

Tags: sql-server, database-mail, format, sp-askbrent

We have an instance that randomly spikes the CPU. I want to create an alert that fires on CPU over 90% and automatically calls a job that runs `sp_AskBrent` and emails me the output. However, the output is unreadable in either Text or HTML output. It doesn't even go well into an Excel spread sheet. How can I get the info in a readable format?

Comment: You can check [my answer](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/122374/507) on another question to run it under PowerShell, it will output an HTML report of the data. Depending on the version of SQL Server you can set that up as a SQL Agent job (PowerShell step), then add in PS code to email the file.

Comment: @ShawnMelton yeah, I came here to post that as well, powershell running it is fairly trivial to then do adhoc formatting.

Answer (score 13):

Make the alert run a job that runs the `EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail` with the `@query` parameter:

```
EXEC dbo.sp_send_dbmail @profile_name = 'mail_profile'
    , @recipients = 'some@mail.com'
    , @subject = 'some subject'
    , @body = 'the body text goes here'
    , @query = 'EXEC sp_AskBrent;'
    , @attach_query_result_as_file = 1;
```

The `@attach_query_result_as_file = 1` parameter will send the results as an attachment in text format, which should certainly be readable.  If you want, you can export the results in comma-delimited format using the `@query_result_separator` parameter.

From the [MSDN page for `sp_send_dbmail`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190307.aspx):

> This example sends an e-mail message to Dan Wilson using the e-mail address danw@Adventure-Works.com. The message has the subject Work Order Count, and executes a query that shows the number of work orders with a DueDate less than two days after April 30, 2004. Database Mail attaches the result as a text file.
>
> ```
> EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
>     @profile_name = 'Adventure Works Administrator',
>     @recipients = 'danw@Adventure-Works.com',
>     @query = 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM AdventureWorks2012.Production.WorkOrder
>                   WHERE DueDate > ''2004-04-30''
>                   AND  DATEDIFF(dd, ''2004-04-30'', DueDate) < 2' ,
>     @subject = 'Work Order Count',
>     @attach_query_result_as_file = 1 ;
> ```

There are many options for that stored proc; check the MSDN page and likely you'll get the output exactly how you want it.